# Visual Studio Web Application using C# to send data to a SQL database issues (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I'm having an issue with my code revolving around cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); and the error: Must declare the scalar variable "@drID1".

The first time i click the button this code is linked too it runs perfectly however when i click again i get the above error. I've messed around with a few different things in this code so there is probably some bad practice in there, but i'm still relatively new to C# so bear with me please.

I just cannot get my head around why it runs perfectly the first time and breaks the second time?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("User id = ******;" +
                                                                        "pwd = *******;" +
                                                                        "Data Source = *******;" +
                                                                        "persist security info = *******;" +
                                                                        "Initial Catalog = *******;"))
        {
            //***************************SQL COMMAND**************************
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ******* (SMSID, RecipientNo, Message, TimeDateSent, Balance, Pending, Code, ErrMsg, drID1, drDestination1, drText1, drReceived1, drCode1, drHasError1, drErrMsg1, drID2, drDestination2, drText2, drReceived2, drCode2, drHasError2, drErrMsg2, Sender) VALUES (@SMSID, @RecipientNo, @Message, @TimeDateSent, @Balance, @Pending, @Code, @ErrMsg, @drID1, @drDestination1, @drText1, @drReceived1, @drCode1, @drHasError1, @drErrMsg1, @drID2, @drDestination2, @drText2, @drReceived2, @drCode2, @drHasError2, @drErrMsg2, @Sender)");

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            //**************************Input Values**************************
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SMSID", sendResult.MessageId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecipientNo", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeDateSent", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", sendResult.MessageBalance);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pending", sendResult.PendingMessages);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", sendResult.Code);
            //Handle error message
            if (sendResult.HasError)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrMsg", sendResult.ErrorMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrMsg", "");
            }
            //Delivery Receipt handling
            var deliveryReceipts = client.GetDeliveryReceipts();
            if (deliveryReceipts.Length > 0)
            {
                //Counter var
                int i = 1;
                //For each Delivery Receipt do this: (there should be only 1 or 2)
                foreach (var deliveryReceipt in deliveryReceipts)
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "DeliveryReceipt Text", "alert('" + i + " - " + deliveryReceipt.Text + "');", true);
                    int c = deliveryReceipts.Count();
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drID1", deliveryReceipt.Id);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drDestination1", deliveryReceipt.Destination);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drText1", deliveryReceipt.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drReceived1", deliveryReceipt.Received);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drCode1", deliveryReceipt.Code);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drHasError1", deliveryReceipt.HasError);
                        //Error handling
                        if (deliveryReceipt.HasError == true)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drErrMsg1", deliveryReceipt.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                        else if (deliveryReceipt.HasError == false)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drErrMsg1", "");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drErrMsg1", "");
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    else if (i == 2)
                    {
                        if (c >= 2)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drID2", deliveryReceipt.Id);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drDestination2", deliveryReceipt.Destination);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drText2", deliveryReceipt.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drReceived2", deliveryReceipt.Received);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drCode2", deliveryReceipt.Code);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drHasError2", deliveryReceipt.HasError);
                            //Error Handling
                            if (deliveryReceipt.HasError == true)
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drErrMsg2", deliveryReceipt.ErrorMessage);
                            }
                            else if (deliveryReceipt.HasError == false)
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drErrMsg2", "");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drErrMsg2", "");
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drID2", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drDestination2", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drText2", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drReceived2", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drCode2", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drHasError2", "");
                            //Error Handling
                            if (deliveryReceipt.HasError == true)
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drErrMsg2", deliveryReceipt.ErrorMessage);
                            }
                            else if (deliveryReceipt.HasError == false)
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drErrMsg2", "");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drErrMsg2", "");
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                i = 1;
            }
            //Execute Query
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sender", System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ******* (SMSID, RecipientNo, 
            Message, TimeDateSent, Balance, Pending, Code, ErrMsg, drID1,
            drDestination1, drText1, drReceived1, drCode1, drHasError1,
             drErrMsg1, drID2, drDestination2, drText2, drReceived2, 
            drCode2, drHasError2, drErrMsg2, Sender) 
VALUES (@SMSID, @RecipientNo, @Message, @TimeDateSent, @Balance, @Pending,
             @Code, @ErrMsg, @drID1, @drDestination1, @drText1, 
            @drReceived1, @drCode1, @drHasError1, @drErrMsg1, @drID2, 
            @drDestination2, @drText2, @drReceived2, @drCode2,
             @drHasError2, @drErrMsg2, @Sender)");
```

That's your command, and evenything with an @ in front of it must have a value supplied as a parameter to the SqlCommand. You only add parameters up to @ErrMsg. The next one is @drID1 which is not defined, just as the error message says.

Even if the value of these parameters is null, you must add a parameter with the @ name and the value of null.

**If there are no delivery receipts then these parameters won't be created and you'll get this error.**

Comment: Thank you for that! Explanation was great too :)

Answer (score 0):

If your `deliveryReceipts.Length == 0` then you will never add the remaining parameters: `@drID1, @drDestination1, @drText1, @drReceived1, @drCode1, @drHasError1, @drErrMsg1, @drID2, @drDestination2, @drText2, @drReceived2, @drCode2, @drHasError2, @drErrMsg2, @Sender`. In your `CommandText`, you list these parameters, so it's expecting them to be there.

If you need to have these as optional, then you will want to create to `CommandText` statements (one with the additional parameters and one without). Then you use the statement that fits you requirements.